# Not start a process if Windowtitle already exists

Tags: batch-file

I have a scheduled task that runs a batch file.  My batch file sets the windowtitle to ProcessErrors.  This batch file can take some time to complete and I don't want multiple to run at a time.  I also do not want to stop the one that is already running as it can cause harm to the process.  I would like to add a line that will check to see if there is already a window open named "ProcessErrors".  If so then it will not start the new one and leave the old one alone.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
REM list all tasks (verbose) and look for "ProcessErrors". If found, exit
tasklist /v |find "ProcessErrors" && goto :eof
REM else continue here (first set my window title)
title ProcessErrors
REM rest of my batch
```